# Fluid in spatially enclosed universe and some additional assumptions?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

### Background

In general relativity I was wondering about the following Universe: Imagine a spatially closed universe containing only a perfect fluid:

$$x'_i =x_i + L_i $$

where $i =1,2,3$ one of the spatial components. Now, the [perfect fluid in thermal equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Stress%E2%80%93energy_of_a_fluid_in_equilibrium) has the stress energy tensor:

$$ T^{\mu \nu} = (\rho + p)u^\mu u^\nu + p g^{\mu \nu} $$

Now assuming the pressure is a function of the $3$ volume and temperature $\theta$ of this universe:

$$ p \equiv p(\int \sqrt{|\det g_{ij}| }  dx_1 \wedge dx_2 \wedge dx_3, \theta)  $$

### Questions

Is it a reasonable assumption to assume the pressure of the universe is a function it's volume? (It seemed intuitive to me but I wasn't sure how to justify it).

What is the corresponding Lagrangian of our stress energy tensor of a fluid which whose pressure depends on the volume of the universe? 
$${\displaystyle T_{\mu \nu }=-2{\frac {\delta {\mathcal {L}}_{\mathrm {M} }}{\delta g^{\mu \nu }}}+g_{\mu \nu }{\mathcal {L}}_{\mathrm {M} }.}$$
(I can't seem to solve the maths)

Also does the line element change by assuming this dependency of pressure on the volume of the universe? If so, what is the new line element?

Comment: there are some very deep/ important ideas here that are not yet widely recognized. the stress energy tensor indeed has deep connections to fluid dynamics but this is rarely remarked on anywhere, its a new research paradigm. possibly there is some cognitive bias against the idea due to it being very similar to the century-old ether idea which is widely regarded as _"disproven"_. following is excellent survey & points to future directions. Tenev + Horstemeyer **The Mechanics of Spacetime - A Solid Mechanics Perspective on the Theory of General Relativity** https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.07655